# How to fix Mailman Bug when Admin Login?

Tags: redhat, mailing-list, mailman

```
 [----- Mailman Version: 2.1.9 -----] 
 [----- Traceback ------] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/mailman/scripts/driver", line 101, in run_main
 main()

 File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admin.py", line 197, in main
show_results(mlist, doc, category, subcat, cgidata)

File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admin.py", line 521, in show_results
  form.AddItem(show_variables(mlist, category, subcat, cgidata, doc))

   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admin.py", line 570, in show_variables
    add_options_table_item(mlist, category, subcat, table, item)

   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admin.py", line 585, in add_options_table_item
     val = get_item_gui_value(mlist, category, kind, varname, params, extra)

 File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admin.py", line 624, in get_item_gui_value
   value = getattr(mlist, varname)

  File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/MailList.py", line 146, in __getattr__
AttributeError: from_is_list
```

I trying login to Admin by throwed error:
Bug in Mailman version 2.1.9

**We're sorry, we hit a bug!
Please inform the webmaster for this site of this problem. Printing of traceback and other system information has been explicitly inhibited, but the webmaster can find this information in the Mailman error logs.**
Please help me fix it! Thanks

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Please help me fix this bug !

Comment: Again, what's the question? This is a stack trace. If you're having trouble with some code you wrote, post enough of the broken code to reproduce the error, and what you've done to try to fix it. If you haven't done so already, I suggest reading through the Help Center, starting with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following answer was given [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/mailman-users@python.org/msg65170.html) by Mark Sapiro:*

There is an issue with the list's data_version attribute vs. Mailman.Version.DATA_FILE_VERSION. When the from_is_list and other new attributes were added, Mailman.Version.DATA_FILE_VERSION was incremented to make it greater than the list's data_version attribute which in turn will cause the lists to be updated the first time they are instantiated.

Perhaps you had some other patches that incremented Mailman.Version.DATA_FILE_VERSION, so that the list's data_version attribute was not < Mailman.Version.DATA_FILE_VERSION causing the update to be skipped.

The way to fix this is to set Mailman.Version.DATA_FILE_VERSION to a value greater than the data_version attribute of the lists.

First run this bash script

```
for l in `/path/to/mailman/bin/list_lists --bare`
do
  /path/to/mailman/bin/dumpdb /path/to/mailman/lists/$l/config.pck |
  grep data_version
done
```

This will print the data_version for each list. If N is the largest such value, edit Mailman/Version.py to change the line

```
DATA_FILE_VERSION = 104
```

to set a value > N. Then visit the listinfo overview page which should update all the lists.

Then so this doesn't happen again, set DATA_FILE_VERSION back to 104 in Mailman/Version.py and create a file containing the single line

```
mlist.data_version = 104
```

and run this bash script

```
cd /path/to/mailman/bin/
for l in `./list_lists --bare`
do
  ./config_list -i /path/to/above/file $l
done
```

That should fix things.

--
Mark Sapiro m...@msapiro.net        The highway is for gamblers,
San Francisco Bay Area, California    better use your sense - B. Dylan